# Extract all single {key:value} pairs from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which maps some keys to 1 or **more** values.

In order to map to more than 1 value, I'm mapping each individual key to a list. How can I get the number of the single pairs? Is there a quick pythonic way to do this?

My dict looks something like this:

```
>>print dict
{'key1':['value11',value12, ...], 'key2': ['value21'], 'key3':['value31', 'value32']}
```

So in the above example, I would expect my output to be `1`

Comment: What you mean by "number of the single pairs"?

Comment: `sum(1 for _, v in dict.items() if len(v)==1)`?

Comment: because there is only **1** key-value pair that has a 1 to 1 ratio`(=1 key, 1 value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through values in dictionary and count:

```
count  = 0
for value in dic.values():
    if len(value) == 1:
        count += 1

print count
```

Comment: Just as a side-note, this would break if OP is using Python 3. Use `values()` to be on the safe side.

Comment: I will post your answer as correct, as it allows me to understand how the iteration works, since I'm very new to Python

Answer (score 2):

With `d` being the dictionary:

```
sum(len(v) == 1 for v in d.values())
```

Or:

```
map(len, d.values()).count(1)
```

(The latter requires `list` around the `map` if you're using Python 3.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
len([_ for v in d.values() if len(v) == 1])
```

where `d` is the name of your dictionary (you should avoid using identifiers such as `dict`, incidentally).

Depending on your interpreter version, you might need to use `itervalues` instead of `values`.

Comment: Your answer works! I accepted @Abhishek Balaji R answer since it gives a better understanding to novices (like me) how the code works on the background

Comment: No problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [@MosesKoledoye's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957159/extract-all-single-keyvalue-pairs-from-dictionary/38957260#comment65268425_38957159) solution for the short (and probably a tiny bit faster) solution, or this naive version:

```
print(len([value for value in d.values()
           if hasattr(value, '__len__') and len(value) == 1]))
```

Comment: I would add a `hasattr(v, '__len__')` in the filter so we don't break when we don't have a list as value; in case.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just filter your dictionary out like this:

```
data = {
    'key1': ['value11', 'value12'],
    'key2': ['value21'],
    'key3': ['value31', 'value32']
}

result = filter(lambda (k, v): len(v) == 1, data.iteritems())
print result, "=>", len(result)
```